# Datetimepicker en fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker

Buenas tardes, podría alguien indicarme desde donde debo llamar en el siguiente código a datetimepicker? tengo dos inputs "start" y "end" en los que quiero que se me despliegue el calendario con la selección de hora también. Gracias.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: moment(),
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            expandThrough: false,
            select: function(start, end) {

                $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                    $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
                });
            },
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

                edit(event);

            },
            eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

                edit(event);

            },
            events: [
            <?php foreach($events as $event): 

                $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $start = $start[0];
                }else{
                    $start = $event['start'];
                }
                if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $end = $end[0];
                }else{
                    $end = $event['end'];
                }
            ?>
                {
                    id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                    id_teach: '<?php echo $event['id_teach']; ?>',
                    id_stud: '<?php echo $event['id_stud']; ?>',
                    title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                    start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                    end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                    color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
                },
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]
        });

        function edit(event){
            start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            if(event.end){
                end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            }else{
                end = start;
            }

            id =  event.id;

            Event = [];
            Event[0] = id;
            Event[1] = start;
            Event[2] = end;

            $.ajax({
             url: 'editEventDate.php',
             type: "POST",
             data: {Event:Event},
             success: function(rep) {
                    if(rep == 'OK'){
                        alertify.alert('Saved');
                    }else{
                        alertify.alert('Could not be saved. try again.'); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Tienes una pregunta casi identica ya: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86412/insertar-datetimepicker-en-input-se-resiste?rq=1

Comment: Sí, es mia pero no saqué nada claro

Comment: @Vieira Te invito a que hagas el [tour] y también te invito a que leas [ask], ya que tus ultimas preguntas las he leído pero no están claras que es lo que quieres lograr, de ser posible añade un [mcve]